# how to install Ubuntu 11.04 to a USB hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Full Ubuntu Install on USB](https://superuser.com/questions/178375/full-Ubuntu-install-on-USB)

how to install Ubuntu 11.04 **to** a USB hard drive .

I have got Windows 7 on my laptop, then I want to install Ubuntu 11.04 to a movable USB dirve
so I can boot from local hard drive or USB drive

Answer (score 1):

But this shouldn't be to hard. All you will need to do is format the USB, select it as your instillation drive - and chose to install a boot loader when the option comes up.

Comment: *assuming the drive is bootable to start with - most new USB drives seem to be, but not all